# What's the footprint of many instances built from a static method at runtime?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I've read articles talking about static class variables loading and static methods loading but very few about returned instantiated objects from static methods and their footprint.

Returning an instance from a static method is actually how singletons are created however singletons are supposed to be created once and then accessed by some getInstance method.

If I voluntarily want to break the singleton pattern, what happens if I write something like the following for example? (note the RandomSumBuilder build() method static access modifier)

```
public class Service {

    public void doSomething() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            System.out.println("Random sum : " + RandomSumBuilder.add().build());
        }
    }
}

public class RandomSumBuilder {
    private List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<>();

    public RandomSumBuilder() { }

    public static RandomSumBuilder add() {
        RandomSumBuilder randomSumBuilder = new RandomSumBuilder();
        randomSumBuilder.aList.add(new Random().nextInt(11));
        return randomSumBuilder;
    }

    public int build() {
        return aList.stream()
                .reduce(Integer::sum)
                .orElse(0);

    }
}
```

To me it's clear RandomSumBuilder can't be considered as singletons but I can't get my head around these questions and I can only make assumptions so far.

1. Are the different RandomSumBuilder instances static?
   *(I'd say yes, like singletons)*
2. Can these objects be elected for garbage collection?
   *(given my answer to question 1, I'd say no)*
3. Does it put unnecessary work on the class loader?
   *(if it has to load that many RandomSumBuilder to instantiate these static objects, I'd say yes since I don't see the point in keeping them global. My quick local test with visualvm couldn't help me decide)*
4. What would the builder pattern (with a nested class) bring here instead?
   *(I'd say way less static objects created and class loading work but being at my 4th consecutive assumption I'm not even sure)*

I hope I'm not too lost in this subject, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: why do you assume they are static? You use a static method to build them, that is all. They are not saved in a static variable, or static List, in this case.

Comment: It's hard to say because your code doesn't even compile. (1) What is `instanceB`? (2) What is `predicateInConstruction`? (3) The `FilteredPredicateBuilder build()` is missing a return statement. (4) You have two parameterless `build()` methods in your class which is not allowed.

Comment: You are definitely reading the wrong articles. Neither “static class variables loading” nor “static methods loading” are a thing. While the individual words exist, these combinations are just gibberish.

Comment: Thank you, I needed to remove this confusion from my mind.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKläger, sorry for this, the snippet it edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your example is not compilable and it is not possible to be sure about what the

> 1. Are the different `RandomSumBuilder` instances static?

That question is meaningless.

There is no such thing as a static instance.  Seriously.

For example:

```
 public class Test {
    public static Test myTest = new Test();
 }
```

The `myTest` *variable* is a static variable, but the *instance* that it points to is no different from any other instance of `Test`.

It is not a "static instance".  *There is no such thing.*

The second issue is that your example is not creating any `RandomSumBuilder` instances at all.

> 2. Can these objects be elected<sup>1</sup> for garbage collection?

Yes.  Assuming that they are not *assigned* to something that makes it reachable.

> 3. Does it put unnecessary work on the class loader?

No.  Unless you are creating multiple classloaders, the class only loaded once.  The classloader doesn't get involved in creating instances.

> 4. What would the builder pattern (with a nested class) bring here instead?

How an object is created makes no difference to its reachability.  It makes no difference that the method that creates it is static, or inner or nested.

On the other hand your code does this:

```
instanceB.aList.add(new Random().nextInt(11));
```

This doesn't compile because `instanceB` is not declared.  But if `instanceB` **was** declared, and it was `static`, then that would be sufficient to make the `Integer` that you are (possibly) creating reachable.

But that is nothing to do with the `build` method being static ...

---

<sup>1 - English mistake: you are equating "candidates" with "election".  Garbage collection is not democratic.   And even in the real world, candidate has a broader meaning than that.  Look it up in a dictionary ...</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I guess I got confused between instances and references.
Sorry about the snippet, I edited it and I hope it makes more sense. Does it change any of your answer?

Comment: *"Does it change any of your answer?"*  - Not materially, no.

Comment: In fact, it is now clear that the `RandomSumBuilder` that is created in `add()` will be a candidate for garbage collection as soon as the `add` call ends.  The fact that `add` is static makes no difference to that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I needed to get out of this confusion state. I have some homework to do but I think I'm on the right path now.